# What word or phrase means "a loss of what was on your mind"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

Sometimes, in the middle of a conversation, a "loss of mind" can affect the speaker. What is the word for that situation and that person ?

Are there more specific terms or phrases than:

- *the loss of mind* (or)
- *empty mindedness*?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that's a "loss of mind".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Unless the intended answer is _insanity_, I doubt it is. But then this whole question is clearly written by someone with limited English proficiency and it’s hard to know exactly _what_ is being asked. A much better fit for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) than ELU.

Comment: Apologies. _I'm pretty sure that that's a "loss of mind" that OP was heading towards._ It's grammatical if semantically inappropriate here.

Comment: Maybe "blackout"?

Comment: It's called a, er... um... Oh, I forget.

Comment: Brain fart. ...

Comment: The original "lost of mind" I quite liked, it suggested someone who could not find their words, someone who is distracted, and perhaps trapped in a maze.  The fact that native speakers rarely say it, doesn't mean it was incomprehensible.

Comment: @AaronHall A Brain Fart is a nonsensical thought, not a loss of mind.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, you nailed it - fixed!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, Yes that is the loss of mind but she asked for one word.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber, may be blockHead

Comment: @vaibhav No. A "blackout" is a temporary failure of memory; a "blockhead" is an idiot.

Comment: @vaibhav I chose to answer the posted question: 'What word or phrase means ...'. Perhaps you missed that.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The most common expression that describes the instance when you suddenly forget what you were about to say is

- [your mind goes blank](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mind+goes+blank)

> I was just about to say something, but my **mind's gone blank**

Alternatively you could use

- [lapse](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lapse)

> I had an awful **lapse of memory** when I was asked to talk about X.

via @Noah

- [slip your mind](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/slip+mind)

> I meant to tell her that Nick had phoned, but it completely **slipped my
>   mind**

Comment: Slipped my mind in AmE.

Comment: @Noah good one. Why didn't I think of it? Must've slipped my mind, you should post it! It's common in BrEng as well.

Comment: Just add it to your post. Would be good to have all the things in one place.

Comment: In the same vein as "mind's gone blank", there is the shortened form "mind-blank". e.g. "I just had a mind-blank."

Comment: @daviewales or as an intransitive verb: **blank** *to become confused or abstracted —often used with "out"* (from m-w.com)  e.g. I blanked when she asked me what my job was.

Answer (score 34):

**Lost my train of thought**, which is kind of the same as **lost track**.

Also if it is due to stress or overload you would say you were **(brain) fried**.

Answer (score 13):

For rhetorical terminology I suggest *[aporia](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/A/aporia.htm)* or *[aposiopesis](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/A/aposiopesis.htm).* In conversational English, this is termed *[drawing a blank](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/draw%20a%20blank)* (link to M-W—see also OED s.v. *draw, v.* 52.b). For slang, this would perhaps qualify as a species of *[brain fart](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Brain%20Fart).*

Comment: I'm not convinced aporia is correct in context. Aposiopesis is more nearly on target, but still has connotations of voluntary discontinuity of expression whereas the question is more about involuntary behaviour.  I'd agree with drawing a blank or brain fart.

Comment: Yes, @JonathanLeffler, naming a rhetorical figure pretty much always implies intentionality, but that implication may be taken with a grain of salt. On the one hand, rhetors lie to audiences by feigning total ignorance of rhetoric: "I am no orator, as Brutus is, / But as you know me all, a plain blunt man." On the other, they lie to each other by having a fancy name for every screwup, whereby they can claim, "Yeah, I *meant* to do that."

Answer (score 10):

In the US, such a lapse is often referred to as a *senior moment.*

Comment: Yes, in Australia too.

Comment: I'm old enough now to plausibly claim to have senior moments. When I was younger, I preferred the phrase "juvenile onset senility".

Answer (score 6):

It is called ***[brain cramp](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brain_cramp)***:

> *(idiomatic)* A temporary mental lapse, such as an inability to remember something, to focus one's attention, to understand something, or to perform some other mental task of which one would ordinarily be capable

Sometimes called *mental cramp* also. It is mistaken with brain fart usually which some sources say that they are same but they are different.

---

[***space out***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/space%20out) can be used as a verb:

> to become inattentive, distracted, or mentally remote

Comment: The phrase "**I just spaced**" is apparently still current: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+just+spaced&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20just%20spaced%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 6):

Consider *draw a blank* and *blank out*.

> [draw a blank](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/draw+a+blank): *Fig.* to fail to remember something
>
> [blank out](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blank+out): *Fig.* to forget something, perhaps on purpose; to blot something out of memory:  *I blanked out your question. What did you say?*

Comment: "Draw a blank" was already given.  As I have commented before, it seems that a good percentage of your answers are regurgitating previous answers.  "Blank out" doesn't even make sense here.  It means something entirely different - it means that you know what the question was but chose to ignore or get rid of it.

Answer (score 3):

try this

at a loss - Puzzled or uncertain what to think, say, or do.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/loss#loss__11

Comment: `At a loss` more implies the problem exhausts the person's capability to deal with it, rather than having a temporary brain lapse.

Answer (score 3):

> **[Wordbound](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/464930/wordbound)**: Unable to find expression in words

&

> **[lethologica](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lethologica)**   the inability to remember a word or put your
>   finger on the right word

&

> **[tip-of-the-tongue phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lethologica) (TOT)** is the failure to retrieve a 
>   word from memory, combined with partial recall and the feeling that 
>   retrieval is imminent

&

completely 'blanking out' falls under **[Short-term memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-term_memory)**

or a

**lapsus    memoriae**, a slip of memory.

Answer (score 2):

It appears there are lots of good terms for this subject. Consider also **brain fade**.

Comment: Or the similar brain fart.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this on here so far; I would add the term "mental block". E.g.

> I was trying to think of a good answer to this question, but I had a complete **mental block** and couldn't remember it.

As another user says, it appears there are a variety of good answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

`mind lapses` is the right word for such resulting action. In rude tone it is also denoted as `Blockhead`.

Answer (score 0):

While not thought about on the order of "mind lapse", this could be a case of temporary [amnesia](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amnesia). It is defined as loss of memory, which is exactly what ... I'm sorry. What was I talking about?

Answer (score -1):

Also consider:
• *[absent-mindedness](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/absent-mindedness#English)* (or *[absentmindedness](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/absentmindedness)*), meaning “The characteristic or state of being easily distracted or preoccupied”;
• *[distracted](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/distracted#English)*, “having one's attention diverted; preoccupied”;
• *[sidetracked](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sidetracked)*, getting diverted or distracted from a main issue or course of action with an alternate or less relevant topic or activity; or deviating briefly from the topic at hand