# "brain-cramp" vs "blank-out"

Tags: meaning, differences

When mind lapses instantly I call it blank-out. Recently I have come across brain-cramp and it is providing almost same meaning as blank-out. Are both same ? Cramp word is not playing big heavy dice here? Since English is not my native language that is why I am asking this.

Comment: I have never hear these terms in english and what do you mean by "mind lapses"? are you referring to a fugue state.

If you mean you have monetarily forgotten something then one might say "oh my mind has gone blank"

"Cramp word is not playing big heavy dice here?" what does this mean!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What word or phrase means “a loss of what was on your mind”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172922).

Comment: The dice game is called "Craps" so you're not referring to dice when you say "brain cramp". :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What word or phrase means "a loss of what was on your mind"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172922/what-word-or-phrase-means-a-loss-of-what-was-on-your-mind)

Answer (score 1):

According to Merriam-Webster.com, a brain cramp is  :  a mental lapse caused especially by carelessness, forgetfulness, or inattention —called also brain fart . That seems to have the meaning you're looking for. "Blank-out" is just a slang term right now.

However, "brain cramp" was just a slang term until recently so I honestly think using either will get your meaning across just fine. Just go with whatever you feel more comfortable saying.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at here, but you seem to be implying that ***blank-out*** is "just a slang term", whereas ***brain cramp*** and ***brain fart*** aren't. Which makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: Well I started off saying they were both slang terms actually! But then I looked at Merriam-Webster and saw the "brain cramp" term, so I was a little thrown off. I had to kind of change what I said and say that it used to be slang. Either way, the point is that either will do just fine.

Comment: Well, it's closed now anyway, but in his broken English OP had already used *when mind lapses*. And your cited definition has [*"a mental lapse"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+mental+lapse%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), which is a standard "non-slang" term for when you don't wish to simply sound frivolous.